# PhpStorm 10 use [command + N] to build a form file on Mac , what is the equivalent procedure on Linux?

Tags: php, phpstorm, symfony

PhpStorm 10.0.3 use [command + N] to build  a form file on Mac. What is the equivalent procedure on Linux?

I am using symfony3 now with PhpStorm.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Keymap by default for this, you have to make it:

Settings => Keymap => Search for "Symfony" => double-clic form => add keyboard shortcut => ...